# Vim-plugin error which goes away when using sudo

Tags: plugin-vim-plug, plugin-managers

After resisting for a bit, I decided to try the plugin manager vim-plug.

It seemed to work well when installing the [GhostText plugin](https://github.com/raghur/vim-ghost), except that I had to do  the installation in a `sudo nvim` session, and the plugin only works when in such a session. If I start my session with the command `nvim` and run the command `:GhostStart`, I get the following error:

[image]

Note: I already changed the owner of the directory ~/.local/share/nvim to myself, and it did not help.

How can I solve this?

EDIT: If I run `:GhostInstall` in a non-sudo session, I get this error:
[image]

and `env | grep ^XDG_` outputs:
[image]

Comment: The GhostText documentation states that the `SimpleWebSocketServer` is `automatically installed as a pip --user dependency when :GhostInstall runs`. You ran `GhostInstall` as root, so it makes sense that it won't be installed for a different user. You mentioned that you `had to do the installation in a sudo nvim session`, but not *why* you had to install it in that way. Could you add some more details to your question explaining this, please?

Comment: @Rich I will update my question.

Comment: Try running the same command on the command-line, to see its output: `python3.6 -m pip install --user -r ~/.local/share/nvim/plugged/vim-ghost/requirements_posix.txt`.

Comment: @filbranden It says that file does not exist. And weirdly enough, if I do ```ls``` in the plugged directory it says it is empty

Comment: Actually, for some reason it seems it's trying to use `/.local` (under the root directory) rather than `~/.local` (under your home directory)... Maybe that's a big part of the problem?

Comment: In your init.vim, do you have anything that would explain the `/.local` from the root? How about the XDG_ variables? Like `env | grep ^XDG_`?

Comment: @filbranden Yes, I had the line ```call plug#begin('/.local/share/nvim/plugged')

)```. I changed it now to ```call plug#begin('/.local/share/nvim/plugged')

)```. But now I simply get the same error (the one of my second screenshot), with ~/.local... instead of /.local... .

Comment: Not sure I understand... Can you fix your init.vim and update the question with latest data please? You might want to remove /.local, since that shouldn't be used, really...